# create a custom button with resizing animation on click

Tags: ios, animation, uibutton, size

I want to create a custom button  with resizing  animation s on touchUPInsideEvent  iOS and . How can i do this?
Thanks in advance.
I have DONE  it using subclassing and these methods:

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event;
- (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event;
```

and using CGAffineTransformMakeScale on touch event.

Comment: can not understand your question.
check it
[backbutton setShowsTouchWhenHighlighted:YES];

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am sorry for miscellaneous question. I just needed  custom animation added to toucpUPinside Event on a button. For those who still wonder You can implemented by subclassing UIButton and with

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event;
- (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event;
```

and  using  CGAffineTransformMakeScale  on touch event.

Comment: suggestion, edit your question in the future instead of add a explanation in a new answer. It will be easier to others understand

Answer (score 0):

I do not know if I understand well your question, but depending on how you create the frame of the button, when in the button is selected use a animation to change the frame´s size and them resize again to the origin.

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:1.0
                 animations:^{
                     CGRect frame = self.button.frame;
                     frame.size.width -= YOUR_VALUE;
                     self.button.frame = frame;
                 }
                 completion:^(BOOL finished){
                     // resize here
                 }];
```

Answer (score 0):

I dont understand well your question. It is my guess

```
[buttonSprite runAction:[SKAction sequence:@[[SKAction scaleTo:0.8 duration:0.1], [SKAction scaleTo:1.0 duration:0.1]]]];
```